# Should I have private members referencing the views of my activity?

Tags: android, performance

I have a simple activity consisting in 4 views defined in an xml file. For the sake of performance, is it better to access my views by their id or to have member referencing them in my activity ? Is it notably different ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `findViewById()` just once for each view that you need to reference in your app. Make this call in `onCreate()` and save the returned view instances in private member variables. Then you can reference them directly later.

findViewById() is expensive, especially if you have a lot of views.

This is pretty much standard Android practice.